# Web bot to login to site not working

Tags: python, bots

I'm trying to get to grips with writing webbots using Python I've had some success so far, but one bot I'm having issues with.

This bot logins into hushmail.com, it'll be run every few days via cron to make sure the account stays active. I'm using mechanize to do the form filling and cookielib to handle the cookies and sessions. It's cobbled together from other scripts I've found.

The form fills correctly when looking at the debugger output in PyCharm, however on submitting the second page form, it doesn't take me to the inbox as expected. Instead it just returns me to the same login form.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mechanize
import cookielib

#login details
my_user="user@hush.com"
my_pass="sampplepass_sdfnsdfakhsk*876sdfj@("

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]


# Open some site, let's pick a random one, the first that pops in mind:
r = br.open('https://www.hushmail.com/')
html = r.read()

print br.title()

print r.info()

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['hush_username']=my_user
br.submit()

print br.title()
print r.info()

br.select_form('authenticationform')
br.form['hush_username']=my_user
br.form['hush_passphrase']=my_pass
br.submit()

print br.response().info()

print br.title()
print br.response().read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the unexpected return HTML values were due to the page returning a mix of Javascript and HTML which mechanize has issues interpreting.

I switch the Python script to use [Selenium Web Driver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) which works much better. handling Javascript generated HTML via a Firefox web driver. I used the handy [Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) to record my actions in a browser and then use the Export > Python Script in the plugin to create the basis for a more robust web bot.